# An example of a non integrable function which has antiderivative.

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, riemann-integration

I am looking for a non Riemannian integrable function which has primitive.

Any idea if such an example exists?

Comment: How about $f = F'$ where $F(x) = x^2\sin(1/x^2)\mathbf{1}_{x \neq 0}$ on $[0,1]$. The derivative is unbounded on $(0,1]$.

Comment: For functions with bounded but non-integrable derivative check Volterra function: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Volterra%27s_function